# How to forbid clang-format to break the line after first call parameter?

Tags: clang, clang-format

I want to write a proper `.clang-format` file for my project. Want to forbid it breaking the line after first argument during function call.

OK:

```
foo(a, b, c);

foo(a, 
    b, 
    c);
```

**NOT OK** (should be forbidden):

```
foo(
    a, b, c);

foo(
    a, 
    b, 
    c);
```

I have tried [available parameters](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), but no success.

Comment: You should always post the .clang-format file you're using for everyone to see because many options can affect the same piece of code. You also didn't state exactly what have you tried.
Providing this data helps you get your answer faster because more people will be interested in answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

For your concrete case you need to set `AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine` to `false`. I think the name is self-explanatory.